# change status to 0 when user close browser

Tags: php, jquery, session

I'am trying to build a simple system to indicate weather the user is online or not. but I have one issue

when the user close the tap or the browser, the ajax code can't refresh the page that handles user track activity.

my php code that change the value to 0 if the user was inactive for 2 minutes

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 61)) {
    $query = "UPDATE  [ccc].[users] SET active = 0 WHERE ldap ='$ldap'";

    sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
}
```

jquery code to check every 5 seconds

```
$(document).ready(function () {
/*check existing users*/
function session_checking() {
    $.post("../ajax-session.php", function (data) {

    });
}
setInterval(session_checking, 5000);
});
```

How can I change the status to 0 if the user closed the browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to notify the server when the user closes the tab/window.

Maybe you could create a task who constantly checks the activity of your users, inactivating them:

```
UPDATE users SET is_online = 0 WHERE is_online = 1 AND last_activity <= [WHAT YOU NEED]
```

Remember to create the proper indexes on your table, considering that you will run the above query frequently.

Comment: Thank you I will try your idea it may work like I want

Comment: Sure, don't forget to vote up my answer if you feel grateful about my help :)

Answer (score 0):

use setcookie for this

```
setcookie('newtest', 'newtest', 0);
```

Comment: but when the user close the browser, the ajax code won't work, so there's no way to reach to if statemen t '(isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 61))       Can you give more details how it works ?

Comment: you should cron file which is run every min if user didn't do any actives for 3 min then you have to unset all session

Answer (score 0):

Simply set a variable which has the session data at login process. So you may check whether user is active or not later. like:

```
$_SESSION["user"] = array(
   "s_name" => "user1@email.com", 
   "login_time" => time()
);


if($_SESSION["user"]["login_time"] < time()+2*60){ unset($_SESSION["user"]); }

in application:
if(isset($_SESSION["user"])){ ... }
```

Comment: so if he closed the browser for 5 hours he will remain active until he come back!.  I don't think this's effective solution. it's good to track how much did the user spent on the site, but not  know if he's online or not

Comment: session will end when browser closed.